# Doctrine 2 ManyToOne with multiple joinColumns

Tags: mapping, left-join, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I'm trying to select the matching row in the product_item_sortorder table based on a productId and toolboxItemId from the product_item table.

In normal SQL that would be for a given productId:

```
SELECT pi.*, pis.* FROM product_item pi
LEFT JOIN product_item_sortorder pis
    ON pi.productId = pis.productId
    AND pi.toolboxItemId = pis.toolboxItemId
WHERE pi.productId = 6
```

I wrote the DQL for it as followed:

```
$this->_em->createQuery(
    'SELECT pi
    FROM Entities\ProductItem pi
    LEFT JOIN pi.sequence s
    WHERE pi.product = ?1'
);
```

Then I get following SQL if I output the $query->getSQL():

```
SELECT p0_.id AS id0, p0_.productId AS productId1, p0_.priceGroupId AS priceGroupId2, p0_.toolboxItemId AS toolboxItemId3, p0_.levelId AS levelId4, p0_.parentId AS parentId5, p0_.productId AS productId6, p0_.toolboxItemId AS toolboxItemId7 FROM product_item p0_ LEFT JOIN product_item_sortorder p1_ ON p0_.productId = p1_. AND p0_.toolboxItemId = p1_. WHERE p0_.productId = ? ORDER BY p0_.id ASC
```

As you can see the referencedColumnNames are not found:

```
LEFT JOIN product_item_sortorder p1_ ON p0_.productId = p1_. AND p0_.toolboxItemId = p1_.
```

Details of the product_item table:

```
+-----+-----------+---------------+
| id  | productId | toolboxItemId |
+-----+-----------+---------------+
| 467 |         1 |             3 |
| 468 |         1 |            10 |
| 469 |         1 |            20 |
| 470 |         1 |             4 |
| 471 |         1 |            10 |
+-----+-----------+---------------+
```

Details of the product_item_sortorder table:

```
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------+
| id  | productId | toolboxItemId | sequence |
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------+
| 452 |         1 |             3 |        1 |
| 457 |         1 |             4 |        6 |
| 474 |         1 |            20 |        4 |
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

ProductItem Entity

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\ProductItem")
 * @Table(name="product_item")
 */
class ProductItem
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductItemSortorder")
     * @JoinColumns({
     *      @JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="productId"),
     *      @JoinColumn(name="toolboxItemId", referencedColumnName="toolboxItemId")
     * })
     */
    protected $sequence;

    ...
?>
```

ProductItemSortOrder Entity

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\ProductItemSortorder")
 * @Table(name="product_item_sortorder")
 */
class ProductItemSortorder
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ToolboxItem")
     * @JoinColumn(name="toolboxItemId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $toolboxItem;

    ...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mappings are seriously wrong. You are using ManyToOne on both ends, how is this possible? You have both associations defined as "owning"-side, no mapped-by or inversed-by (See Association Mappings chapter). And you are using join columns of one association to map to many fields in another entity. I suppose you want to do something else, can you describe exactly your use-case?

Comment: I updated the question a little bit and below you can see which query I want to execute

Answer (score 1):

How you would map your example in YAML (since @Hernan Rajchert's example is only in annotations):

```
ProductItem:
    type: entity

    manyToOne:
        sequence:
            targetEntity: ProductItemSortorder
            joinColumns:
                productId:
                    referencedColumnName: productId
                toolboxItemId:
                    referencedColumnName: toolboxItemId
```